# rails view not defaulting to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple controller with a `show` and a `index` method. `routes.rb` has a `resources :foo` entry and when I go to `localhost:3000/foo` I get an `missing template` error even though I have an `index.json.jbuilder` file in the correct folder which is easily enough shown when I go to `/foo.json`

Shouldn't rails see that there isn't a html template for this particular view and use the json template automatically?

I am using rails 4.2.

Comment: Rails wouldn't see it that way. You have to specify the format explicitly. To which all formats would that file be rendered. By default due to the file extension the file `index.json.jbuilder` will be rendered only for json request calls. Or else rails will throw a templet error.

Comment: If you want to render same file for all formats you can do like `render 'index.json.jbuilder', :formats => [:html, :xml, :js, :json]` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going to `localhost:300/foo` will by default use the `:html` format. Since you don't have the corresponding html view, you'll get the *missing template* error. If you want the route to default to `:json` you can specify it when defining the route

```
resources :foo, defaults: {format: :json}
```

Answer (score 1):

From official [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html):

> The next part of the message contains a hash. The :locale key in this hash simply indicates what spoken language template should be retrieved. By default, this is the English - or "en" - template. **The next key, :formats specifies the format of template to be served in response. The default format is :html, and so Rails is looking for an HTML template.** The final key, :handlers, is telling us what template handlers could be used to render our template. :erb is most commonly used for HTML templates, :builder is used for XML templates, and :coffee uses CoffeeScript to build JavaScript templates.

This is why Rails can't find your `.json.jbuilder` view. So, in your case you can pass correct `Accept` HTTP header or override request format:

```rb
before_filter :default_request_format

def default_request_format
  request.format = :json
end
```

or specify it in routes as described @Bart Jedrocha above.